# ORA-29268, 400 - Bad Request trying to send Tweet using REST Api from PL/SQL using UTL_HTTP. What am I missing?

Tags: oracle, api, rest, plsql, twitter

I'm trying to write a PL/SQL function that lets me send a tweet using REST API from Oracle PL/SQL

I've successfully tested this using Postman, and I'm trying to recreate now in Oracle PL/SQL but whatever I do I get a 400 Bad Request when I try and use the utl_http.set_header command.

In the details below, I've changed the values of the various keys, so it's not that, I'm just hiding them here.

I know its not ACL problems as I've got that set up as initially I had ACL errors which after creating ACL I now dont have.

In the Postman console, this is what I have :

```
POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Test%20Tweet

Request Headers
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXX",oauth_token="YYY",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1604040422",oauth_nonce="uAmCX0NFeym",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="KhtY25DnOvYHgqK6SG83UvMU5y4%3D"
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8901fa98-f367-4219-a33e-23d38d316650
Host: api.twitter.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: personalization_id="v1_QQUZtSSL3H/TMxogtXMEcw=="; lang=en; guest_id=v1%3A160397589280743625
Content-Length: 0
```

and that works fine.

Below is the code that I have trying to recreate the same thing from PL/SQL, that errors every time.

I've never done this before so apologies if I'm missing something obvious, but I could really do with some help!  Thanks.

```
DECLARE
    http_req                   utl_http.req;
    http_resp                  utl_http.resp;
    l_http_method              VARCHAR2(5) := 'POST';
    l_content                  VARCHAR2(140) := utl_url.escape('SAHTestTweet');
    l_oauth_request_token_url  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';
    l_oauth_consumer_key       CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := 'XXX';
    l_oauth_consumer_secret    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := 'YYY';
    l_oauth_token              CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := 'AAA';
    l_oauth_secret             CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := 'BBB';
    l_oauth_nonce              VARCHAR2(500);
    l_oauth_signature_method   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10) := utl_url.escape('HMAC-SHA1');
    l_oauth_timestamp          VARCHAR2(100);
    l_oauth_version            CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := utl_url.escape('1.0');
    l_oauth_base_string        VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_oauth_key                VARCHAR2(500) := l_oauth_consumer_secret
                                 || '&'
                                 || l_oauth_secret;
    l_oauth_header             VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_sig_mac                  RAW(2000);
    l_base64_sig_mac           VARCHAR2(100);
    l_update_send              VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_line                     VARCHAR2(1024);
    resp_name                  VARCHAR2(256);
    resp_value                 VARCHAR2(1024);
    l_random                   VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN  

 -- Oracle Wallet
        utl_http.set_wallet('file:/home/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/owm/wallets/oracle', 'PASSWORDHERE');

 -- Get the timestamp  
      SELECT
        utl_url.escape((sysdate - TO_DATE('01-01-1970', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) *(86400))
    INTO l_oauth_timestamp
    FROM
        dual;  
  
  -- RANDOM oauth_nonce  
      SELECT
        dbms_random.string('A', 25)
    INTO l_random
    FROM
        dual;

    SELECT
        utl_url.escape(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_random, 'AL32UTF8')))
    INTO l_oauth_nonce
    FROM
        dual;

-- Build up base string

    l_oauth_base_string := l_http_method
                           || ' '
                           || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_request_token_url)
                           || '?'
                           || 'status'
                           || '='
                           || l_content
                           || '&'
                           || utl_url.escape('oauth_consumer_key'
                                             || '='
                                             || l_oauth_consumer_key
                                             || '&'
                                             || 'oauth_nonce'
                                             || '='
                                             || l_oauth_nonce
                                             || '&'
                                             || 'oauth_signature_method'
                                             || '='
                                             || l_oauth_signature_method
                                             || '&'
                                             || 'oauth_timestamp'
                                             || '='
                                             || l_oauth_timestamp
                                             || '&'
                                             || 'oauth_token'
                                             || '='
                                             || l_oauth_token
                                             || '&'
                                             || 'oauth_version'
                                             || '='
                                             || l_oauth_version);

    dbms_output.put_line(l_oauth_base_string);
    
    -- create signature
    l_sig_mac := dbms_crypto.mac(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_oauth_base_string, 'AL32UTF8'), dbms_crypto.hmac_sh1,
                                utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_oauth_key, 'AL32UTF8'));

    dbms_output.put_line('Combined sig: ' || l_oauth_key);
    
    -- encode signature
    l_base64_sig_mac := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(l_sig_mac));
    
    dbms_output.put_line('MAC Signature (Base64-encoded): ' || l_base64_sig_mac);
    
    
    -- add tweet to end of URL
    l_update_send := l_oauth_request_token_url
                     || '?status='
                     || l_content;
                     
    dbms_output.put_line('BEGINNING REQUEST ' || l_update_send);
    http_req := utl_http.begin_request(l_update_send,
                                      l_http_method,
                                      utl_http.http_version_1_1);
                                      
    dbms_output.put_line('REQUEST BEGUN URL ' || l_update_send);
    
    utl_http.set_response_error_check(true);
    utl_http.set_detailed_excp_support(true);
    utl_http.set_body_charset(http_req, 'UTF-8');
    
    -- Create Header
    l_oauth_header := 'OAuth '
                      || 'oauth_consumer_key="'
                      || l_oauth_consumer_key
                      || '",'
                      || 'oauth_token="'
                      || l_oauth_token
                      || '",'
                      || 'oauth_signature_method="'
                      || l_oauth_signature_method
                      || '",'
                      || 'oauth_timestamp="'
                      || l_oauth_timestamp
                      || '",'
                      || 'oauth_nonce="'
                      || l_oauth_nonce
                      || '",'
                      || 'oauth_version="'
                      || l_oauth_version
                      || '",'
                      || 'oauth_signature="'
                      || utl_url.escape(l_base64_sig_mac)
                      || '"';

    dbms_output.put_line('HEADER: ' || l_oauth_header);
    
    -- Set Header Fields
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Authorization', value => l_oauth_header);
```

** THE LINE ABOVE IS WHAT CAUSES THE CODE TO FAIL **

```
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'User-Agent', value => 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.1');

    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Accept', value => '*/*');

    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Cache-Control', value => 'no-cache');

    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Postman-Token', value => '8901fa98-f367-4219-a33e-23d38d316650');

    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Host', value => 'api.twitter.com');

    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Accept-Encoding', value => 'gzip, deflate, br');

    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Connection', value => 'keep-alive');

    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Content-Length', value => '0');

    utl_http.set_transfer_timeout(to_char('60'));
    utl_http.write_text(r => http_req, data => l_content);
    http_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => http_req);
    dbms_output.put_line('GETTING RESPONSE HEADERS! ');
    FOR i IN 1..utl_http.get_header_count(http_resp) LOOP
        utl_http.get_header(http_resp, i, resp_name, resp_value);
        dbms_output.put_line(resp_name
                             || ': '
                             || resp_value);
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line('Getting content:');
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            utl_http.read_line(http_resp, resp_value, true);
            dbms_output.put_line(resp_value);
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('No more content.');
    END;

    utl_http.end_response(r => http_resp);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('HTTP ERROR: ' || sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm);
END;
```

The DBMS output I'm getting looks right generally :

```
POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=SAHTestTweet&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_nonce=53334A3365474E5A636D52765A304E3353323532536E4252533270515330523654513D3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1604062895&oauth_token=YYY&oauth_version=1.0

Combined sig: g9nkIeE1j5VKUam1hCMXJuanMAXWuhvq8wDQugmQh9fzjnzVLQ&o3m9EgdWOLbcjN7KUACeXXdWyVyrvB8Zx1bCCgt7Z1Shi

MAC Signature (Base64-encoded): j3fvwUjuy6KaHxY487tHMMcwP3U=

BEGINNING REQUEST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=SAHTestTweet
REQUEST BEGUN URL https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=SAHTestTweet

HEADER: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXX",oauth_token="YYY",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1604062895",oauth_nonce="53334A3365474E5A636D52765A304E3353323532536E4252533270515330523654513D3D",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="j3fvwUjuy6KaHxY487tHMMcwP3U="

HTTP ERROR: ORA-29268: HTTP client error 400 - Bad Request
```

I'm guessing it's only something small as everything seems to match the Postman console.

Comment: Could you include your `l_oauth_base_string` output? It looks like you're url-escaping the `&` and `=`, which [is not right](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature). But idk if that's the problem or not.

Comment: @kfinity  Thanks for the feedback - sorry I didnt make it clear, the first DBMS output line you see in the section above is l_oauth_base_string

Comment: You should also sort the oauth headers in alphabetical order. I can see that is not the case in what you're seeing in the Postman console, so that's a little confusing, but it is a requirement.

Comment: Oh - I think your issue is that by default, [utl_url.escape](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_url.htm#ARPLS71589) does **not** escape reserved characters like `&` and `=`, but it should. Compare your base string to the [twitter example](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature).

Comment: @AndyPiper Thank you - I will do that.

Comment: @kfinity thanks, I'll try and hardcode one for now then.  I'm a bit  confused though, I followed the link you sent and it shows :
status=Hello%20Ladies%20%2b%20Gentlemen%2c%20a%20signed%20OAuth%20request%21

There is no escaping around the = after the status on that page, maybe its the @. I will give it a try, thanks so much

Comment: @kfinity hmm, not sure that's right.
I've just done : 

select utl_url.escape('this = my @ script') from dual;

and it returns : 

this%20=%20my%20@%20script

Answer (score 1):

I apologize, my first comment was exactly backwards - reserved characters *should* be escaped. But I think the problem is probably the signature.

Your signature base string:

```
POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=SAHTestTweet&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_nonce=53334A3365474E5A636D52765A304E3353323532536E4252533270515330523654513D3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1604062895&oauth_token=YYY&oauth_version=1.0
```

Twitter's example string:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&include_entities%3Dtrue%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog%26oauth_nonce%3DkYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318622958%26oauth_token%3D370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DHello%2520Ladies%2520%252B%2520Gentlemen%252C%2520a%2520signed%2520OAuth%2520request%2521
```

There's a few differences there:

- POST should be followed by a "&", not " "
- Reserved characters (&=/?:) are not getting escaped
- `status=l_content` should be at the end of the parameter string

For the second point, whenever you call `utl_url.escape()`, you should pass `TRUE` as the second argument. Along with that, here's what I'd change in your code:

```
l_oauth_base_string := l_http_method
                       || '&'
                       || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_request_token_url, TRUE)
                       || '?'
                       || utl_url.escape('oauth_consumer_key'
                                         || '='
                                         || l_oauth_consumer_key
                                         || '&'
                                         || 'oauth_nonce'
                                         || '='
                                         || l_oauth_nonce
                                         || '&'
                                         || 'oauth_signature_method'
                                         || '='
                                         || l_oauth_signature_method
                                         || '&'
                                         || 'oauth_timestamp'
                                         || '='
                                         || l_oauth_timestamp
                                         || '&'
                                         || 'oauth_token'
                                         || '='
                                         || l_oauth_token
                                         || '&'
                                         || 'oauth_version'
                                         || '='
                                         || l_oauth_version
                                         || '&'
                                         || 'status'
                                         || '='
                                         || l_content,
                                         TRUE);
```

I ran your example with those changes, and it looks a lot more like Twitter's example now:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json?oauth_consumer_key%3DXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D53334A3365474E5A636D52765A304E3353323532536E4252533270515330523654513D3D%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1604061356%26oauth_token%3DAAA%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DSAHTestTweet
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that - I'd got some way down that route, but hadn't spotted that bit about needing & after POST, so that's really useful.  Still getting 400, but I'm sure I'll spot it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT A WORKING ANSWER YET.**

Well there's been some improvement, the request seems to be correct now and it's the authorization that's failing.    So a 401 instead of a 400.

Will keep this updated with progress until I get there in case it helps anyone else.

Code now is :

`code`

```
DECLARE
    http_req                   utl_http.req;
    http_resp                  utl_http.resp;
    l_http_method              VARCHAR2(5)            := 'POST';
    l_tweet_content            VARCHAR2(140)          := 'SAHTestTweet';
    
    l_oauth_request_token_url  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';
    l_oauth_consumer_key       CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := '1112QVhZR8Mpv60B0Zzdaqzxh';
    l_oauth_consumer_secret    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := '222kIeE1j5VKUam1hCMXJuanMAXWuhvq8wDQugmQh9fzjnzVLQ';
    l_oauth_token              CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := '3331548309900005376-bn4mDbpI00d0wGW4ikEvSR7xmuIA3d';
    l_oauth_token_secret       CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := '4449EgdWOLbcjN7KUACeXXdWyVyrvB8Zx1bCCgt7Z1Shi';
    l_oauth_signature_method   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10)  := 'HMAC-SHA1';
    l_oauth_nonce              VARCHAR2(500);
    l_oauth_timestamp          NUMBER;
    l_oauth_version            CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5)   := '1.0';
    l_sig_base_string          VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_sig_parameter_string     VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_signing_key              VARCHAR2(500)          := utl_url.escape(l_oauth_consumer_secret,TRUE)||'&'||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_token_secret,TRUE);
--    l_signing_key              VARCHAR2(500)          := l_oauth_consumer_secret||'&'||l_oauth_token_secret;
--    l_signing_key              VARCHAR2(500)             := utl_url.escape(l_oauth_consumer_secret,TRUE)||'&';
    l_oauth_header             VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_sig_mac                  RAW(2000);
    l_oauth_signature          VARCHAR2(100);
    l_update_send              VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_line                     VARCHAR2(1024);
    resp_name                  VARCHAR2(256);
    resp_value                 VARCHAR2(1024);
    l_random                   VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN  

  -- Oracle Wallet
  utl_http.set_wallet('file:/home/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/owm/wallets/oracle', 'Oracle123!Oracle123!');

 -- Get the timestamp  
  SELECT (sysdate - TO_DATE('01-01-1970', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) *(86400)
  INTO   l_oauth_timestamp
  FROM   dual;  
      
  -- RANDOM oauth_nonce  
  SELECT dbms_random.string('A', 25)
  INTO l_random
  FROM  dual;

  SELECT utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_random, 'AL32UTF8'))
  INTO   l_oauth_nonce
  FROM   dual;
    
-- Build up parameter string for signature calcuclation

  l_sig_parameter_string  := 
                  utl_url.escape('include_entities',TRUE)
                ||'='
                ||utl_url.escape('true',TRUE)
                || '&'                        
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_consumer_key',TRUE)
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_consumer_key ,TRUE)
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_nonce',TRUE)  
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_nonce,TRUE)  
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_signature_method',TRUE)  
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_signature_method,TRUE) 
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_timestamp',TRUE)  
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(TRUNC(l_oauth_timestamp),TRUE)  
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_token',TRUE)  
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_token,TRUE)  
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_version',TRUE)
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_version,TRUE)  
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('status',TRUE)
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_tweet_content,TRUE)
                ;
  
  dbms_output.put_line('SIG PARAMETER STRING : '||l_sig_parameter_string );
  
  l_sig_base_string :=  l_http_method   
                       || '&'  
                       || utl_url.escape (l_oauth_request_token_url,TRUE)  
                       || '&'                            
                       || utl_url.escape (l_sig_parameter_string ,TRUE);

    dbms_output.put_line('SIGNATURE BASE STRING : '||l_sig_base_string);
    
    -- create signature
    l_sig_mac := dbms_crypto.mac(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_sig_base_string, 'AL32UTF8'),
                                 dbms_crypto.hmac_sh1,
                                 utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_signing_key,     'AL32UTF8')
                                );
    -- bas64 encode signature
    l_oauth_signature := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(l_sig_mac));
    
    dbms_output.put_line('OAUTH Signature (Base64-encoded): ' || l_oauth_signature);  
    
    -- add tweet to end of URL
    l_update_send := l_oauth_request_token_url
                     || '?status='
                     || l_tweet_content;
                     
    dbms_output.put_line('BEGINNING REQUEST ' || l_update_send);
    http_req := utl_http.begin_request(l_update_send,
                                       l_http_method,
                                       utl_http.http_version_1_1);
                                      
    dbms_output.put_line('REQUEST BEGUN URL ' || l_update_send);
    
    utl_http.set_response_error_check(true);
    utl_http.set_detailed_excp_support(true);
    utl_http.set_body_charset(http_req, 'UTF-8');
    utl_http.set_transfer_timeout(to_char('60'));
    
    -- Create Authorization Header
    l_oauth_header := 'OAuth '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_consumer_key',TRUE)
                      || '="'
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_consumer_key,TRUE)
                      || '", '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_nonce',TRUE)
                      || '="'
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_nonce,TRUE)   
                      || '", '   
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_signature',TRUE)
                      || '="'
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_signature,TRUE)
                      || '", '                      
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_signature_method',TRUE)
                      || '="'
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_signature_method,TRUE)
                      || '", '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_timestamp',TRUE)
                      || '="'
                      || utl_url.escape(TRUNC(l_oauth_timestamp),TRUE)
                      || '", '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_token',TRUE)
                      || '="'
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_token,TRUE)
                      || '", '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_version',TRUE)
                      || '="'
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_version,TRUE)
                      || '"'
;

    dbms_output.put_line('AUTHORIZATION for Header: ' || l_oauth_header);
    
    -- Set Header Fields
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Accept',         value => '*/*');
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Connection',     value => 'keep-alive');
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'User-Agent',     value => 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.1');
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Content-Type',   value => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');    
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Authorization',  value => l_oauth_header);
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Content-Length', value => '0');
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Host',           value => 'api.twitter.com');
 
 dbms_output.put_line('HEADERS SET.  NOW WRITING CONTENT');   
    utl_http.write_text(r => http_req, data => l_tweet_content);
 dbms_output.put_line('WILL NOW GET RESPONSE');   
    http_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => http_req);
    dbms_output.put_line('GETTING RESPONSE HEADERS! ');
/* 
    FOR i IN 1..utl_http.get_header_count(http_resp) LOOP
        utl_http.get_header(http_resp, i, resp_name, resp_value);
        dbms_output.put_line(resp_name
                             || ': '
                             || resp_value);
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line('Getting content:');
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            utl_http.read_line(http_resp, resp_value, true);
            dbms_output.put_line(resp_value);
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('No more content.');
    END;

    utl_http.end_response(r => http_resp);
    */
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('HTTP ERROR: ' || sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm);
END;
```

Which comes back with :

```
SIG PARAMETER STRING : include_entities=true&oauth_consumer_key=1112QVhZR8Mpv60B0Zzdaqzxh&oauth_nonce=5245315162475A4C54324A425957744F62315A495A32465756316C6A61474A6154413D3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1604322884&oauth_token=3331548309900005376-bn4mDbpI00d0wGW4ikEvSR7xmuIA3d&oauth_version=1.0&status=SAHTestTweet
SIGNATURE BASE STRING : POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&include_entities%3Dtrue%26oauth_consumer_key%3D1112QVhZR8Mpv60B0Zzdaqzxh%26oauth_nonce%3D5245315162475A4C54324A425957744F62315A495A32465756316C6A61474A6154413D3D%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1604322884%26oauth_token%3D3331548309900005376-bn4mDbpI00d0wGW4ikEvSR7xmuIA3d%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DSAHTestTweet
OAUTH Signature (Base64-encoded): vU0M0LpAAkpNQUWXQUYGRMdKzFs=
BEGINNING REQUEST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=SAHTestTweet
REQUEST BEGUN URL https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=SAHTestTweet
AUTHORIZATION for Header: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="1112QVhZR8Mpv60B0Zzdaqzxh", oauth_nonce="5245315162475A4C54324A425957744F62315A495A32465756316C6A61474A6154413D3D", oauth_signature="vU0M0LpAAkpNQUWXQUYGRMdKzFs%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1604322884", oauth_token="1281548309900005376-bn4mDbpI00d0wGW4ikEvSR7xmuIA3d", oauth_version="1.0"
HEADERS SET.  NOW WRITING CONTENT
WILL NOW GET RESPONSE
HTTP ERROR: ORA-29268: HTTP client error 401 - Authorization Required
ORA-29268: HTTP client error 401 - Authorization Required
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Ok so I finally got there.

Turns out the Twitter documentation on how to build the signature is significantly incorrect (at least when calling from Oracle).

The document says your signature header should have "include entities" in it, this causes the code not to work.
Remove this from the signature string, start with consumer key.

Next, the Twitter documentation says the signing key, which is consumer secret & oauth token secret should be percent escaped either side of the &, this is wrong, these 2 parts should NOT be escaped.

It says the oauth header sections (consumer key, nonce etc) should have a " around the values - they shouldnt.

Finally, the list of header fields MUST begin with Authorization, the documentation shows Accept, Connection, User-Agent, Content-Type coming before Authorization and this does not work.

This leaves my WORKING code as :

```
DECLARE
    http_req                   utl_http.req;
    http_resp                  utl_http.resp;
    l_http_method              VARCHAR2(5)            := 'POST';
    l_tweet_content            VARCHAR2(140)          := 'Test2' ;
    
    l_oauth_request_token_url  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';
    l_oauth_consumer_key       CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := '1112QVhZR8Mpv60B0Zzdaqzxh';
    l_oauth_consumer_secret    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := '222kIeE1j5VKUam1hCMXJuanMAXWuhvq8wDQugmQh9fzjnzVLQ';
    l_oauth_token              CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := '3331548309900005376-bn4mDbpI00d0wGW4ikEvSR7xmuIA3d';
    l_oauth_token_secret       CONSTANT VARCHAR2(500) := '4449EgdWOLbcjN7KUACeXXdWyVyrvB8Zx1bCCgt7Z1Shi';
    l_oauth_signature_method   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10)  := 'HMAC-SHA1';
    l_oauth_nonce              VARCHAR2(500);
    l_oauth_timestamp          NUMBER;
    l_oauth_version            CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5)   := '1.0';
    l_sig_base_string          VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_sig_parameter_string     VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_signing_key              VARCHAR2(500)          := l_oauth_consumer_secret||'&'||l_oauth_token_secret;
    l_oauth_header             VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_sig_mac                  RAW(2000);
    l_oauth_signature          VARCHAR2(100);
    l_update_send              VARCHAR2(2000);
    l_line                     VARCHAR2(1024);
    resp_name                  VARCHAR2(256);
    resp_value                 VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_random                   VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN  

  -- Oracle Wallet
  utl_http.set_wallet('file:/home/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/owm/wallets/oracle', 'Oracle123!Oracle123!');

 -- Get the timestamp  
  SELECT (sysdate - TO_DATE('01-01-1970', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) *(86400)
  INTO   l_oauth_timestamp
  FROM   dual;  
      
  -- RANDOM oauth_nonce  
  SELECT dbms_random.string('A', 25)
  INTO l_random
  FROM  dual;

  SELECT utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_random, 'AL32UTF8'))
  INTO   l_oauth_nonce
  FROM   dual;
    
-- Build up parameter string for signature calcuclation
  l_sig_parameter_string  := 
                utl_url.escape('oauth_consumer_key',TRUE)
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_consumer_key ,TRUE)
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_nonce',TRUE)  
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_nonce,TRUE)  
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_signature_method',TRUE)  
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_signature_method,TRUE) 
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_timestamp',TRUE)  
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(TRUNC(l_oauth_timestamp),TRUE)  
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_token',TRUE)  
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_token,TRUE)  
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('oauth_version',TRUE)
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_oauth_version,TRUE)  
                ||'&'  
                ||utl_url.escape('status',TRUE)
                ||'='  
                ||utl_url.escape(l_tweet_content,TRUE)
                ;
  
    l_sig_base_string :=  l_http_method   
                       || '&'  
                       || utl_url.escape (l_oauth_request_token_url,TRUE)  
                       || '&'                            
                       || utl_url.escape (l_sig_parameter_string ,TRUE);
   
    -- create signature
    l_sig_mac := dbms_crypto.mac(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_sig_base_string, 'AL32UTF8'),
                                 dbms_crypto.hmac_sh1,
                                 utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_signing_key,     'AL32UTF8')
                                );
    
    -- bas64 encode signature
    l_oauth_signature := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(l_sig_mac));
    
    -- add tweet to end of URL
    l_update_send := l_oauth_request_token_url
                     || '?status='
                     || utl_url.escape(l_tweet_content,TRUE);
                     
    http_req := utl_http.begin_request(l_update_send,
                                       l_http_method,
                                       utl_http.http_version_1_1);
                                      
    
    utl_http.set_response_error_check(true);
    utl_http.set_detailed_excp_support(true);
    utl_http.set_body_charset(http_req, 'UTF-8');
    utl_http.set_transfer_timeout(to_char('60'));
    
    -- Create Authorization Header
    l_oauth_header := 'OAuth '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_consumer_key',TRUE)
                      || '='
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_consumer_key,TRUE)
                      || ', '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_nonce',TRUE)
                      || '='
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_nonce,TRUE)   
                      || ', '   
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_signature',TRUE)
                      || '='
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_signature,TRUE)
                      || ', '                      
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_signature_method',TRUE)
                      || '='
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_signature_method,TRUE)
                      || ', '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_timestamp',TRUE)
                      || '='
                      || utl_url.escape(TRUNC(l_oauth_timestamp),TRUE)
                      || ', '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_token',TRUE)
                      || '='
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_token,TRUE)
                      || ', '
                      || utl_url.escape('oauth_version',TRUE)
                      || '='
                      || utl_url.escape(l_oauth_version,TRUE)
;
    
    -- Set Header Fields
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Authorization',   value => l_oauth_header);    
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Accept',          value => '*/*');
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Connection',      value => 'keep-alive');
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Content-Length',  value => '0');
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Content-Type',    value => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');    
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Host',            value => 'api.twitter.com');
    utl_http.set_header(r => http_req, name => 'Cache-Control',   value => 'no-cache');

    utl_http.write_text(r => http_req, data => utl_url.escape(l_tweet_content,TRUE));
    http_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => http_req);

    FOR i IN 1..utl_http.get_header_count(http_resp) 
    LOOP
        utl_http.get_header(http_resp, i, resp_name, resp_value);
        dbms_output.put_line(resp_name
                             || ': '
                             || resp_value);
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line('Getting content:');
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            utl_http.read_line(http_resp, resp_value, true);
            dbms_output.put_line(resp_value);
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN utl_http.end_of_body 
        THEN dbms_output.put_line('No more content.');
    END;

    utl_http.end_response(r => http_resp);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('HTTP ERROR: ' || sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm);
END;
```